Make R code (dada2 package) run multithreaded on HPC computer (submitted via slurm)
My R code doesn't run in parallel on a HPC cluster and I don't understand why. According to the dada2 documentation, if an integer is specified for the multithreaded = # flag, it's passed to setThreadOptions() and this number of cores will be used, but sujeff [username] tells me it still uses 1 core only.
CPU_Efficiency    Number_of_CPUs_In_Use
16.30%    (0.98 of 6)

Number_of_CPUs_In_Use does sometimes increase to 1.05, but never higher.
Loading the dada2 library should be enough for this to work according to the documentation (it automatically loads the Rcpp package, too), but as I can see that setThreadOptions() is part of  RcppParallel, I tried loading this package in addition, which didn't help, however.
This is the bash slurm script to submit the R script
#! /bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --mail-user=mail@mail.de
#SBATCH --partition=x
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=6
#SBATCH --mem=20GB
#SBATCH --time=00-12:00:00
#SBATCH --qos=standard

module add R-bundle-Bioconductor/3.16-foss-2022b-R-4.2.2
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 R --no-save

mpirun -n 1 Rscript script.R ${SLURM_NTASKS} 

This is script.R
setwd("/wd")
library("dada2")
library("RcppParallel")
load("data.RData")

ddF <- dada(derepF, err = errF, multithread = 6)
ddR <- dada(derepR, err = errR, multithread = 6)

Everything works perfectly and delivers the expected result, except that it doesn't run in parallel. Can someone help me figure out why?
I tried so far: specifying ${SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK} instead of ${SLURM_NTASKS} in the bash script, running it with and without loading library("RcppParallel") and setting multithread = TRUE.

I figured it out, the error was in the mpirun command. -n must specify the number of parallel processes, too:
mpirun -n 12 Rscript script.R ${SLURM_NTASKS}

I didn't change anything else of what I originally posted and it works! Loading the RcppParallel package is not necessary.

Note that dada2 uses the unix fork and OMP for parallelization. It uses the multithreading parameter to control mclapply() parallelization with the unix fork, and the OMP parameter for the OpenMP parallelization used by RcppParallel. To specify cores per task (task = an instance of your R script), use #SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12 for 12 cores.
The parameters --ntasks and n= in mpirun specify how many copies of your Rscript to run. This does not enable multithreading within your script but just runs 12 copies of your script, all giving the same results. To see substantial speedup in your code, you should run
#! /bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --mail-user=mail@mail.de
#SBATCH --partition=x
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12
#SBATCH --mem=20GB
#SBATCH --time=00-12:00:00
#SBATCH --qos=standard

module add R-bundle-Bioconductor/3.16-foss-2022b-R-4.2.2
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 R --no-save

Rscript script.R ${SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK} 

without mpirun and specify multithread=cores in your dada2 function calls. I assume your R script would pick up the argument cores with commandArgs() from ${SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK} on the Rscript command line.
There is also an OMP parameter in some functions that engage the RcppParallel parallelization, which should be configured so cores are not oversubscribed (multithread*OMP <= 12). But you should run some experiments to balance the best combination of OMP and multithread two-level parallelism, possibly with other than 12 cores.
Of course, if you want MPI distributed-memory parallelism on top of the multithreading, you can use more nodes with MPI (engaged with mpirun) and the pbdMPI package to manage combining their results. So you can get a total of three levels of parallelism this way by running several instances of your R script, each configured for different results (via MPI ranks).
